# How to restore Windows boot option in grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I used to have two harddrives sda (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) and sdb (Window 7). I used grub2 to boot between both of them.

Then, I did a clean install of Ubuntu 13.10 on sda replacing the old Ubuntu version. I think, this install automatically changed boot to UEFI if I'm not mistaken.

Now, the Windows boot option doesn't show up anymore in grub menu and I have no way to boot into my Windows 7 installation anymore, which I need to do occassionally.

How can I restore it? Do I need to revert back to a previous boot mechanism prior UEFI (which one?)? What would be of interest to debug this?

sdb1 is the boot partition of Windows 7 (ntfs)

My Linux partitions are encrypted.

Comment: Your EFI-vs-BIOS configuration is not 100% clear, but the proper solution is reliant on getting this detail right. Thus, I recommend you run the [Boot Info Script,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) post the `RESULTS.txt` file it generates to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the resulting URL here. That should clarify the issue and avoid dead-ends caused by people making incorrect guesses about your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Grub2 should be able to find windows using `sudo update-grub`. If that does not work, maybe your partition table is damaged and you should use a livecd or a tool like [super grub disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to recover it.

More info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657134

**Edit:** You cannot have both OS with different boot system. If one is with EFI/UEFI, the other should be installed using the same system.

Comment: `sudo update-grub` didn't help, so I will look into the thread you linked later today. But in general, it should work that I can still use my old Windows boot-table even now grub uses the EFI stuff?

Comment: It should work in both methods (EFI and BIOS) but the UEFI is the currently recommended method, [as theorically it's better than the BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface). I've found more information [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Preliminary_requirements) (it's for ArchLinux, but should be very similar)

Comment: After learning a bit more... **You cannot have two OS installed using different BIOS systems**. Both must be in the same system (or BIOS or EFI/UEFI).